# Can not receive battery status and Name of Nest protect

Tags: nest-api

From past few days the nest protect devices created using nest simulator tool are not responding properly. All of the nest protect are having same name Entryway and the battery status field is not updating in the Json response of  Rest streaming . Is there anything I can do to fix this issue .

**NOTE :previously I was able to get all the update properly**

Following is the response I'm receiving:

```
{
    "structure_id": "5vPPJJbCkUvNlf6JiLSY6eQaHKjf2iMd5YO4LsWuakUUiiU_M0jqKg",
    "where_id": "45oC0YSjNKW13CclRc5F5DMrlsCCmp4VKVPaF1WQMBbd2FAAO-GqMg",
    "name": "Entryway",
    "name_long": "Entryway Nest Protect",
    "is_online": true,
    "device_id": "Hqw7qr2DPBzVp6Wrqds6hs8AFPWfjT7T",
    "is_manual_test_active": false
}
```

My permissions are Away read/write ,Thermostat read/write ,Smoke+CO alarm read.

Comment: It looks like the name is in that response?

Comment: this name is default for every device I m adding and there is different name on simulator .@Enigma

Comment: Have you tried deleting the structure & virtual devices and recreating them? If you are mixing real with virtual devices I have seen some peculiar issues.

Comment: yes tried it many times and there are no real devices with me . even my testing team accounts are also getting same issues @Enigma

Comment: Ok it's possible you aren't subscribing to the right part of the message. See https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference - You'll want to make sure you can see `"smoke_co_alarms": [ "RTMTKxsQTCxzVcsySOHPxKoF4OyCifrs", ... ],`